# Clarifying the differences of Javascript, Ruby,and Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby, coffeescript

Can someone give me a rough breakdown or the main points of the differences between these 3 languages? Any key syntax or structures I should look out for? It seems like they each are syntax differently and it gets quite confusing at times. Any tips, good reads, or clarification would help greatly, thanks!

Comment: It's like comparing a raisin, a grape, and a car ?

Comment: They're all wrinkly when crushed?

Comment: The question lacks Fortran, Japanese, and Haskell for comparison, after all, they use different syntax, which no doubt is confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my attempt to summarize the three for you:

JavaScript is the most popular, generally the easiest to pick up for a beginner, and generally a good choice for learning.

- JavaScript runs pretty much everywhere, on every system, and inside every web browser. A couple popular JavaScript libraries are jQuery and Node.js.
- Key syntax/structures: the language is prototype-based, not class-based. This gives JavaScript great flexibility, and it feels quite different from other languages.

Ruby is an object-oriented programming language, and is similar in flavor to perl and python.

- Ruby is especially popular for building web applications, thanks to many popular libraries, most notably Ruby On Rails and Sinatra.
- Key syntax/structures: Ruby is written like perl and python, and it's close in spirit to LISP and Smalltalk, which enables many kinds of dynamism, reflections, and domain specific languages.

Coffeescript is a kind of meta-language related to JavaScript. Coffeescript aims to provide a better syntax, better meaningful coding conventions, and to protect the developer from mistakes.

- Coffeescript typically compiles to JavaScript. Coffeescript is similar to Microsoft TypeScript, and semi-similar to Google's Dart language, in the sense of aiming to improve on the idea of JavaScript.
- Key syntax/structures: the syntax is much shorter than JavaScript, and many people find it much easier to read/write. If you read "JavaScript: The Good Parts" then you'll know a lot about how the Coffeescript syntax/structures are important.

While you're learning, my advice is to focus on JavaScript. There are many more people using it, writing tutorials for it, and developing software related to it.